# Can antique versions of TFS generate a changelog report?

Tags: version-control, tfs, changelog

Don't ask why, but I'm using VS2003 and need to see what changes have taken place in all the files in my project between a certain date and now. I see how I can do that, namely by right-clicking on each file and selecting "Compare Versions" then selecting By Date and the date for the version to compare with the latest. This is good; what would be (much) better is if I could generate a report whereby it would show me something like:

```
The line "*Sit on a potato pan Otis*" was removed from BachBestsMozart.cs.
The line "*Any enterprise requiring new duds is likely a dud itself*" was added to CheapSunglasses.cs
(etc.)
```

...but hopefully ignore unimportant differences, such as formatting, comments, etc.

Does such a possibility exist, or am I doomed to open each file, one by one?

### UPDATE

I ended up having to compare them all, one by one, eyeballing them. At least it's better than VS2010 is acting for me right now:

Awedly (I am awed, but not in a good way), the "Compare" functionality in VS2010 doesn't hold a candle to that in VS2003!

In VS2003, I can select a Target Version based on a date to compare with the current version - so, if I pick 2/13/2013, I may end up comparing files dated recently (today or whenever the file was last modified) and one modified on 2/13/2013, or 2/1/2013, or whenever the last modification prior to the date I selected took place.

In VS2010, it *looks* like I should be able to do that, but the combo box for the comparison file is grayed out/inacessible! Heavens to Murgatroid!!!

Or maybe this is just related to the problem I'm having where I can't update anything in the Package Manager - even trying to update Nuget gives me a can't load library err msg; and the package console is "read only" for me, too... I wish there were a "repair" functionality built into VS that would check up on missing or corrupt DLLs and replace them...